# One Column Table Data In One Page RDLC

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I am working for qrcode inventory system where some datails embedded in qrcode that can be scan by phone.
my problem i want to print one column data that is the qrcode in the database
after 5 qrcode it will go to next page in print preview I want the 6th qrcode at the same page
btw i am using picturebox inside a table example

from:

```
1st page
___________________________________
|qrcode 1|
|qrcode 2|
|qrcode 3|
|qrcode 4|
|qrcode 5|
____________________________________
2nd page
____________________________________
|qrcode 6|
|qrcode 7|
|qrcode 8|
|qrcode 9|
|qrcode10|
_____________________________________
```

TO

```
 ___________________________________
    |qrcode 1| |qrcode 6|
    |qrcode 2| |qrcode 7|
    |qrcode 3| |qrcode 8| 
    |qrcode 4| |qrcode 9|
    |qrcode 5| |qrcode10|
____________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround I can think of on the spot, would be to add a second table (almost identical) just next to it. And show/hide the rows depending on the `RowNumber`, this will allow you to fit more on a single page but the ordering will be slightly different.

Using the [RowNumer Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-rownumber-function) you can define the following expressions for the rows on each table:

```
//Table1 - Row Visibility:
=IIF(RowNumber("MyDataSet") Mod 2, True, False) 

//Table2 - Row Visibility:
=IIF(RowNumber("MyDataSet") Mod 2, False, True)
```

Here is an illustration of what is going to happen. Making a row invisible will also remove the space, moving the next row up.

> [--*Table1*--] [--*Table2*--] 
>   |qrcode 1| <strike>|qrcode 1|</strike> 
>  <strike>|qrcode
>   2|</strike> |qrcode 2|
>  |qrcode 3| <strike>|qrcode 3|</strike>
>   
>  <strike>|qrcode 4|</strike> |qrcode 4|
>  |qrcode 5|
>   <strike>|qrcode 5|</strike> 
>  <strike>|qrcode 6|</strike> |qrcode
>   6|
>  ...

This should get the following result, which is ofcourse slightly different than from your example:

> |qrcode 1| |qrcode 2| 
>   |qrcode 3| |qrcode 4| 
>   |qrcode 5| |qrcode 6| 
>   |qrcode 7| |qrcode 8| 
>   |qrcode 9| |qrcode10|

Comment: I used matrix column inside that there is the tablix 
using columngroup expression =ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/5)
it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem could be solved setting `Columns` and `ColumnSpacing` properties of your report:

1. display `Property` window
2. click on `Report` (grey area outside your page)
3. find and set `Columns` property

Please note that using old versions of Visual Studio you can find `Columns` in `Body` properties.